Where are Credit Card Authorizations Stored in Magento 2?
We are currently looking at setting up a Magento store for our business. We have an existing ERP system which we currently use for capturing funds for authorized amounts, and would prefer to be able to load the credit card authorizations from the Magento store into our ERP system so operations can continue as normal.
In order to facilitate this, I'm trying to determine where in the Magento data this information is stored. I've review a few tables and I'm not seeing any columns for this authorization number. I do see columns for the amounts and transaction ids in the sales_order_payment table, but do not see any actual authorization numbers.
Would anyone know how the credit card authorization numbers are stored, and if it would be possible to pull this value into another system for capturing?
